# How to execute the output result for execute immediate statment

Tags: oracle

From the below query i am getting the output as below. but i am expecting the output result like the output select query to be executed again and provide the result .
Also, i want to remove the UNION ALL from last line of the output like this

```
 select A from Table1 Union all
 Select A from table2 Union All
 Select A from table3 Union all
 Select A from table4;
```

Query :

```
 SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
 Declare
  v_sql varchar2(500);
  v_sql2 varchar2(500);
 v_prj_id varchar2(4000):='ProjectA,ProjectB,ProjectC,ProjectD';

 BEGIN


 Dbms_Output.Put_Line('v_prj_id='||v_prj_id);
 --
 FOR i IN (SELECT trim(regexp_substr(v_prj_id, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) l
        FROM dual 
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(v_prj_id, ',') + 1 
       ) LOOP

   v_sql :=  'select '''|| i.l ||''' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ' || i.l || 
  '.Table UNION ALL';

 Dbms_Output.Put_Line (v_sql);

   --
  END LOOP;
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql ;

  v_sql2 :=  RTRIM (v_sql, 'UNION ALL');
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql2 ;
  Dbms_Output.Put_Line (v_sql2);

  END;
   /
```

```
Output :
    select 'ProjectA' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ProjectA.event UNION ALL
    select 'ProjectB' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ProjectB.event UNION ALL
    select 'ProjectC' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ProjectC.event UNION ALL
    select 'ProjectD' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ProjectD.event UNION ALL
```

Comment: What happens? Don't you get an exception on `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql ;` as this query still has a trailing `UNION ALL`? And for `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql2 ;` you must tell the DBMS where to put the results, i.e. add a `BULK COLLECT INTO` clause in order to fill an array. Or use `OPEN <refcursor> FOR <query>;` instead of `EXECUTE IMMIDEATE`.

Answer (score 3):

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` will not provide you the `SELECT` statement results.

From [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/EXECUTE-IMMEDIATE-statement.html#GUID-C3245A95-B85B-4280-A01F-12307B108DC8)

> If dynamic_sql_statement is a SELECT statement, and you omit both into_clause and bulk_collect_into_clause, then execute_immediate_statement never executes.

You have use `SELECT INTO` clause or `BULK_COLLECT_INTO_CLAUSE` and assign the values to some variable if you want to see the results of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` select values.

Something like below for single row

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  L_RESULT VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  VSQL:= --YOUR LOGIC
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE VSQL INTO L_RESULT;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(L_RESULT);
END;
/
```

For Multiple rows

```
DECLARE
  TYPE T IS TABLE OF MYTABLE.ID%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  MYROW T;
BEGIN
  VSQL:= --YOUR LOGIC
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE VSQL BULK COLLECT INTO MYROW;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(MYROW.XXX);
 END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything right except concatenating the v_sql with original string -

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
 Declare
  v_sql varchar2(500);
  v_sql2 varchar2(500);
 v_prj_id varchar2(4000):='ProjectA,ProjectB,ProjectC,ProjectD';

 BEGIN


 Dbms_Output.Put_Line('v_prj_id='||v_prj_id);
 --
 FOR i IN (SELECT trim(regexp_substr(v_prj_id, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) l
        FROM dual 
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(v_prj_id, ',') + 1 
       ) LOOP

   v_sql := v_sql || ' select '''|| i.l ||''' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email, modified_by, modified from ' || i.l || 
  '.Table UNION ALL';

 Dbms_Output.Put_Line (v_sql);

   --
  END LOOP;
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql ;

  v_sql2 :=  RTRIM (v_sql, 'UNION ALL');
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql2 ;
  Dbms_Output.Put_Line (v_sql2);

  END;
   /
```

Comment: i want to remove the Union all from the last line of output

Output :
    select 'ProjectA' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ProjectA.event UNION ALL
    select 'ProjectB' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ProjectB.event UNION ALL
    select 'ProjectC' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ProjectC.event UNION ALL
    select 'ProjectD' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ProjectD.event UNION ALL